# How to make a ListView or PageView with Circle Items in Flutter and resizing the current Circle bigger?

Tags: android, listview, flutter, dart

Something like this: https://i.gyazo.com/2d60f65a1801eaaa58bcb1e795f7edec.png with circles.
Is it also possible to do something like this https://gyazo.com/f58e4c5db30013a832b70a839fdc1c03 ?

Answer (score 1):

```
 //declare these
 PageController _pageController = PageController(viewportFraction: 0.5);
 int selectedPage = 0;
 List yourList =[];


 //in initState method
    _pageController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        selectedPage = controller.page;
      });
    });

  //inside body

     PageView(
          controller: _pageController,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            if (index == selectedPage) {
               Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  height:300.0,
                  width:300.0,
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                         backgroundImage: yourList[index],
                       //modify as you want
                      )
                )
            }
             else {
              Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottom,
                  height:100.0,
                  width:100.0,
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                         backgroundImage: yourList[index],
                       //modify as you want
                      )
            }
          },
          itemCount: yourList.length,
        ),
```

Comment: Did you mean index == selectedPage instead of position == selectedPage ?

Comment: Yes ! I' Sorry !